# Как создать программу для сортировки hex кода

Tags: python-3.x, hex

Решил создать маленькую программку которая принимает 16-ричный код

```
646с726а77206а6с6с6548
```

И преобразует в

```
\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64
```

Но не понимаю как это сделать?

Были попытки

```
a = "646с726а77206а6с6с6548"
b = a[::-1]
hexcode = ""
for i in b:
    hexcode+=b
```

Но я не знаю как можно сделать, так чтобы цикл выбрасывал по 2 символа?

Comment: Обращение строк по два символа? `for i in range(0, len(a), 2):     hexcode = a[i:i+2] + hexcode` но это не "питонично" ;)

Comment: почему по два?! я бы хотел в переменную `hexcode = "\x" `падало по два символа что бы вышло "\x48\x65\x6c"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так получается:

```
a = '646с726а77206а6с6с6548'
hexcode = ''.join([r'\x' + a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)])
print(hexcode) # \x64\x6с\x72\x6а\x77\x20\x6а\x6с\x6с\x65\x48

hexcode = ''.join(reversed([r'\x' + a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]))
print(hexcode)  # \x48\x65\x6с\x6с\x6а\x20\x77\x6а\x72\x6с\x64
```